# Forma mais performática de trabalhar com Request em ASP Clássico?

Tags: variáveis, asp, visual-basic-6, request

Estou trabalhando em uma página web que usa ASP Clássico e fiquei com uma dúvida,
armazenar o valor de um request em uma variável melhora o desempenho quando comparado à ficar usando o request("valor") ao longo do código?

O melhor é assim?

```
if Request("valor") > 0 AND cond1 Then
   ...
Elseif Request("valor") < 0 AND cond2 Then
   umaVar = Request("valor") + 2
End If
```

Ou assim

```
Dim dblValor : dblValor = Request("valor")
if dblValor  > 0 AND cond1 Then
   ...
Elseif dblValor  < 0 AND cond2 Then
   umaVar = dblValor  + 2
End If
```

Ou não há diferença?

**EDIT:**
Uma motivação para a duvida:
Quando enviamos n dados para capturar com o request, entre eles o "valor", ao realizar a chamada Request("valor") eu tenho um endereço único de memória a ser consultado ou existe algo semelhante a uma lista ou dicionário que a aplicação precisa percorrer, na pior das hipóteses n registros, toda vez que for feita a chamada?
Não sei como funciona o comportamento do request mas encontrei que o ASP faz um busca* para saber se é um Request.Form, ou Request.QueryString e assim por diante, mas e no armazenamento desses valores?

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Olá Seffrin, sua pergunta está um pouco mais ou menos, você poderia colocar um código para melhorar o entendimento de quem vai responder? De preferência um código mais completo, exemplificando sua dúvida.

Comment: Dei uma editada, acho que ficou mais claro agora.

Comment: Acredito que a performance não será alterada nas duas formas expostas, porem se levarmos em consideração a manutenção do código criar uma variável para armazenar o valor seja o melhor caminho; já que ficará um ponto único de entrada. Supomos que um dia vc resolva altera o nome de "valor" para "xpto" terá que alterar em todos os pontos, já se você atribuir a uma variável terá que alterar apenas em um único local. Vc também deveria considerar que Request("valor") poderá não vir carregado com um valor monetário e isso ria resultar em um erro na aplicação.

Comment: Fiz uma edição para ilustrar melhor o que gerou a duvida, pois não sei como funciona o comportamento do request. Sei que ele faz um busca para saber se é um Request.Form, ou Request.QueryString e assim por diante, mas e no armazenamento desses valores?

Answer (score -3):

Muito melhor atribuir o `request()` à uma variável:

```
variavel = request("variavel")
```

Alem do código ficar mais enxuto, fica bem melhor de trabalhar com o dado recebido, principalmente caso haja necessidade de trata-los:

```
variavel = trim(replace(replace(request("variavel"),"'",""),"_",""))
```

Imagina ter que repetir `trim(replace(replace(request("variavel"),"'",""),"_",""))` cada vez que vc quiser pegar o `request()`? E se vc quiser depois mudar a forma de tratar o `request()`? Teria que alterar todo o código. Usando uma variável para o `request()` isso se torna bem mais simples.